# Missing Keyword

Tags: sql

I am creating a new table and I kept running into some error saying that I am missing keyword. The logic that I wanna include in the script is like,

if ncB.out_fno = 13100, then return ncB.out_fid. else, left join with the table gc_nr_connect ncC on ncC.in_fid = ncB.out_fid. if ncC.out_fno =1310- return ncC.out_fid.

It seems like a loop but I have no idea how to do it.

```
CREATE TABLE SGTEL10.FTP
AS (
select r.g3e_fid as riser_fid, cbl.g3e_fid as riser_cbl_fid, elem2.ownership as cbl_ownership, 
onu.g3e_fid as FTP_FID, 
CASE WHEN ncB.out_fno = 12100 then ncB.out_fid else ncC.in_fid = ncB.out_fid  
END FTP_FID
FROM gc_riser_temp r
JOIN gc_contain_temp cbl on cbl.g3e_ownerfid = r.g3e_fid AND r.ltt_id in (0,888888888)
JOIN gc_netelem_temp elem2 on elem2.g3e_fid = cbl.g3e_fid AND elem2.ltt_id in (0,888888888)
LEFT JOIN gc_nr_connect_temp ncA on ncA.g3e_fid = cbl.g3e_fid AND ncA.ltt_id in (0,888888888)
LEFT JOIN gc_nr_connect_temp ncB on ncB.in_fid = ncA.out_fid AND ncB.ltt_id in (0,888888888)
LEFT JOIN gc_nr_connect_temp ncC on ncC.in_fid = ncB.out_fid and ncC.ltt_id in (0,888888888) 
LEFT join gc_onu_temp onu on onu.g3e_fid = ncB.out_fid AND onu.ltt_id in (0,888888888));
```

Comment: You might need to specify the column names and data types of your new table

Comment: here `else ncC.in_fid = ncB.out_fid` what you are trying do it? You are trying to assign the value. In `select` you can't assign. What value should be printed when `ncB.out_fnp` is not 12100?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and not all DBMS support the standard `create table .. as select ...` Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

you can write it as

```
select * into new_table from table
```

**Query**

```
select r.g3e_fid as riser_fid, cbl.g3e_fid as riser_cbl_fid, elem2.ownership as cbl_ownership, 
onu.g3e_fid as FTP_FID, 
CASE WHEN ncB.out_fno = 12100 then ncB.out_fid else ncC.in_fid = ncB.out_fid  
END FTP_FID
into  SGTEL10.FTP
FROM gc_riser_temp r
JOIN gc_contain_temp cbl on cbl.g3e_ownerfid = r.g3e_fid AND r.ltt_id in (0,888888888)
JOIN gc_netelem_temp elem2 on elem2.g3e_fid = cbl.g3e_fid AND elem2.ltt_id in (0,888888888)
LEFT JOIN gc_nr_connect_temp ncA on ncA.g3e_fid = cbl.g3e_fid AND ncA.ltt_id in (0,888888888)
LEFT JOIN gc_nr_connect_temp ncB on ncB.in_fid = ncA.out_fid AND ncB.ltt_id in (0,888888888)
LEFT JOIN gc_nr_connect_temp ncC on ncC.in_fid = ncB.out_fid and ncC.ltt_id in (0,888888888) 
LEFT join gc_onu_temp onu on onu.g3e_fid = ncB.out_fid AND onu.ltt_id in (0,888888888))
```

Comment: yeah but it wouldnt be a temporary table in the server right? HAHA I need to create it as a temporary table in the server because I will be querying this table later in my script.

Comment: for temporary table you can write it as #temp or #ftp.  # will create it as temporary table.